# Tags and SEF URLs - Wrong Page

Tags: tags, sef

Joomla 3.3.3

I have no redirects in place, not in the .htaccess or the Joomla redirect component. The problem is that when a user clicks on a tag they are redirected to the wrong article.

For example, if you click on the tag 'guide' the actual link is http://www.mywebsite.com/component/tags/tag/10-guide but the user is redirected to http://www.mywebsite.com/10-guide and this returns a 404 error.

When other tags are clicked you either get a 404 error or a random article from the website.

Is this a known issue? Has anyone run into this before?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: I have found a way around this but it's not ideal. Basically I created a new menu (I have not assigned a module to the menu) and created a new menu item for each tag (Tags » Compact list of tagged items). The example link in my post is now http://www.mywebsite.com/guide and it works as it should. You could put the links in a submenu with a parent of 'Tags' so that the link would be http://www.mywebsite.com/tags/guide

Comment: What are you using to get the links for the tags? A particular module or view?

Comment: The links are simply the ones where you click on the tag on the website.

Answer (score 1):

Does this work with SEF URLs switched off? Try turning off SEF URLs, clear the cache and click on a tag (in the front end) again to see if this resolves the issue. If it does then it may be an issue with your SEF URLs